# OpenID server with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, openid

We have an existing user database (in our SMF forum) and we want to setup an OpenID server so that our users can use their account to login also on other sites.

The user database can be accessed via MySQL and we can only use PHP on that server.

I stumbled upon [www.openidoo.com](http://www.openidoo.com/) but that doesn't seem to work. At least on their demo page, I created a user account and tried to link that to my SourceForge account but SourceForge just always says "There was an error using your OpenID.". If it would have worked, I would have hacked it somehow that it uses the user accounts from the SMF forum instead.

Any other suggestion?

Thanks,
Albert

Comment: This question is about servers, networks or the administration of many machines, and is a better fit for Server Fault.

Comment: Have you tried linking via OpenID against any other sites other than SourceForge? I've had similar issues with SourceForge and using OpenID against my own server which works fine to authenticate with here on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coded it myself now:

http://github.com/albertz/smf-openid-server

Answer (score 0):

I'm running [Community-ID](http://source.keyboard-monkeys.org/projects/show/communityid), a PHP-based OpenID server.  Setup was really easy, only have a few dozen users authenticating against it, but haven't had any issues in the year or so that it's been up.

Comment: Linked website is returning "500" errors.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/communityid/files/?source=navbar although it is quite old.